# I have a problem with react and npm run build

Tags: reactjs, express, build

When I try to `npm run` build it shows me this error

```
$ npm run build

> express@3.2.2 build
> cross-env GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
```

how can I know what is causing it?
this is my build script

```
"build": "cross-env GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build",
```